# How I can create own driver for variables in powershell

Tags: wpf, powershell, xaml, new-psdrive

I whant to create driver for own variables in own scope.
For example `$myown:name = value`

I tried to do that with different values for `-Root`:

```bsh
New-PSDrive -Name myown -PSProvider Variable -Root /myown/
```

But that driver works like `variable:`.

```bsh
compare (ls myown:) (ls variable:)
# no changes
```

How to create psdriver for variables that will work not like `variable:` psdrive?

`$variable:name` and `$myown:name` must be different.

*Edited1:*

#### What I want to do

I'm going to create module for loading **WPF** forms from *.xaml*.
And all elements with `x:Name` property must be imported to new PSDriver named like loaded form.

```bsh
Load-WPF form1.xaml -OutVariable form1
$form1 # loaded WPF form
# and all form's elements added to form1: provider
$form1:button1  # <Button  x:Name="button1"  ../>
$form1:textbox1 # <TextBox x:Name="textbox1" ../>
```

Comment: What exact problem are you trying to solve here? If you create a variable in module scope or a local script scope it will only be available there anyways

Comment: Ditto with what Mathias said, and are you sure you are looking at the New-PSDrive cmdlet use case correctly?  For example as per the docs [-Root
Specifies the data store location to which a PowerShell drive is mapped.]

Comment: Why do they have to be a drive? When I do it I simply create a vaiable to store all of it... `$SyncHash.Window`,`$SyncHash.Button1`,`$SyncHash.TextBox1`...